# Styling Turf buffer based on marker attribute

Tags: leaflet, switch-statement, buffer

As title suggests, i'm trying to style the Turf buffers around my marker layer based on attributes from that marker layer.

I know how to style a layer based on attributes of that **SAME** layer but am having trouble connecting the style to the buffers instead.

I have played with two methods, both of which are able to style my buffers but still don't connect to my marker's attribute information (for obvious reasons as you will see). Please ignore any strange formatting as the post rearranged things and I tried to fix them.

Attempt 1:

```
lyrHouses = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [],
};

// parse local CSV file

Papa.parse("src/data1/Houses.csv", {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  skipEmptyLines: true,
  complete: function (results) {
    results.data.forEach((house) => {
      feature = {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [house.Longitude, house.Latitude],
        },
        properties: {
          Location: house.Location,
          Type: house.Type,
        },
      };

      mrkHouses = L.geoJSON(feature).addTo(mymap);

      lyrHouses.features.push(feature);
      houseBuffer = turf.buffer(mrkHouses.toGeoJSON(), 3, {
        units: "kilometers",
      });
      lyrTest = L.geoJSON(houseBuffer, {
        style: function (feature) {
          switch (feature.properties.Type) {
            case "Duplex":
              return { color: "blue" };

            case "Quadplex":
              return { color: "yellow" };
          }
          return { color: "red" };
        },
      }).addTo(mymap);
    });
  },
});
```

Attempt 2:

```
function setBuffColor(d) {
  return d = 'Duplex' ? "green" :
    d = 'Quadplex' ? "red" :
    d = 'Semidetached' ? "blue" :
    '#FFED80';
}

function BuffStyle(feature) {
  return {
    color: setBuffColor(feature.properties.Type),
  };
}
```

Comment: Does the `houseBuffer` GeoJSON structure have any `properties`?

Comment: houseBuffer does not have any properties. That's where I was running into problems as I needed to grab them from my markers that had been updated with CSV parsed attributes. However, @Anatoly Sukhanov solution seems to have worked! Thank you for responding nonetheless Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not like this?

```
lyrTest = L.geoJSON(houseBuffer, { style: house.Type === 'Duplex' ? { color: "blue" } : (house.Type === 'Quadplex' ? { color: "yellow" } : { color: "red" }) });
```

Comment: This worked surprisingly. As i'm still learning JS and Leaflet as I go, sometimes it becomes difficult to clearly understand which variables are objects, layers, geoJSONs and how to access attributes, all while maintaining proper formatting. I won't make this particular mistake again, fortunately. Thank you!

Comment: This might be a stupid question Anatoly but how can I create an overlay layer from the markers and buffers so that I can toggle these on/off. I can't figure out which portion to define as the new overlay.

Comment: I should have been more specific. None of the variables in the original code above (Attempt 1) are viable layers. Even when I declare lyrHouses as a variable, it is empty and doesn't include any of the markers/buffers created within. How can I store these markers/buffers as a valid geoJSON layer.

Comment: This is how I would implement it if I get you right - https://anatolysukhanov.com/stackoverflow/leaflet/buffer.html

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out how to alter my code to accommodate the new variables but this worked smoothly. Double thanks!